# Is Flatland unique?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

Is the depiction of life in two dimensions unique to [*Flatland: A Romance of Many Dimensions*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatland), or has another author written on this topic?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphereland

Comment: @PaulL It's a derivative of the movie Flatland (2007), which was based on the 1884 novel. I'm looking for a novel or short story. But thanks.

Comment: Try clicking that link rather than making assumptions.  It's a novel, written in 1965.

Comment: There is also Rudy Rucker's 2003 novel *Spaceland*, but doesn't actually describe 2-dimensional life..  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceland_(novel) http://www.rudyrucker.com/spaceland/

Comment: @PaulL It's a sequel to Flatland, by a different author. I guess this qualifies, but I was hoping for someone giving a different treatment to the idea.

Comment: A. K. Dewdney's [The Planiverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planiverse)...

Comment: Yes.  It is very flat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you mentioned you don't want a direct sequel, there is also [*The Planiverse*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Planiverse) which tries to be much more realistic about the biology, chemistry and physics of a 2D universe. [Here](https://battypip.wordpress.com/2012/01/06/favourite-books-of-2011-flatland-the-planiverse/) is a blog entry with a summary and a snapshot of a diagram from the book showing the anatomy of a 2D being (not a cross-section of course, but rather the whole being, inside and out, as viewed from our 3D perspective above the 2D plane it lives in):

[image]

There's a higher-resolution version of this image in [this pdf](http://math2033.uark.edu/wiki/images/5/58/Planiverse.pdf) which summarizes some of the tricky aspects of a 2D world that are addressed in the book.

Another summary of this and other books inspired by *Flatland* can be found [here](http://www.wongery.com/week/Arde), about *The Planiverse* it says:

> Dewdney's Arde is a far more thorough and rigorous depiction of a two-dimensional world than any produced before it. Drawing not only on his own conclusions and speculations but on correspondence with physicists, biologists, and other experts who communicated with him privately or as part of a symposium, Dewdney develops not only the life of Arde, but its physics and, to a very limited degree, its chemistry. Even just in terms of Arde's biology, Dewdney goes into much more detail than any of his predecessors. He describes a dozen organisms aside from the Nsana, both fauna—from the tiny Zar Hyet to the formidable Bes Sallur—and flora—from the aquatic Ilma Kabosh to the terrestrial Jirri Basla. He also delves where Abbott, Hinton, and Burger did not into the anatomy of his two-dimensional beings, discussing, for instance, the "zipper organs" that make it possible for fluid to circulate through their bodies without their separating into discrete parts. Dewdney does not neglect to discuss the culture of the nsana, either, going so far as to develop their musical instruments and even a board game of sorts, "Alak", that they play on a one-dimensional board.

Finally, another book that like *Sphereland* is written as a direct sequel to *Flatland*, but which may be of interest since it deals with many more modern mathematical topics like fractional dimensions, is [*Flatterland*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatterland) by Ian Stewart. There's a review [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2001/04/21/books/shelf-life-discovering-dimensions-beyond-imagining.html) which says:

> Things have gotten considerably more complex since the Euclidean universe of ''Flatland'' was described. So when, in ''Flatterland,'' A. Square's great-great-granddaughter, Victoria Line, comes across her ancestor's samizdat manuscript and seeks a similar visitation, she is not just lifted into 3-D space. She is shown ''spaces with infinitely many dimensions, spaces with none, spaces with fractional dimension, spaces with finitely many points, curved spaces, spaces that get mixed up with time, and spaces that aren't really there at all.'' In other words she is invited to see the surfaces and worlds imagined by recent theoretical mathematics and physics.
>
> Along the way -- and it is a knotty, twisting and appropriately contorted way -- we encounter geometrical universes in which all parallel lines meet or doughnuts easily turn into coffee cups. Malleable rubber spaces like those imagined in mathematical topology (with their ''bendy plastic shapes'' and their ''surreal baroque worms'' are evoked without too much difficulty. Victoria also comes across intriguing oddities that show just how far mathematical imagination can go, including a creature whose interior is equivalent to a sphere but whose exterior is not.

Comment: Thanks so much. The torus/coffee cup morph reminds me of the joke about why you shouldn't invite a mathematician for coffee+. I have a problem wrapping my head around the interior sphere idea though...

Answer (score 6):

[*An Episode of Flatland: or How a Plane Folk Discovered the Third Dimension*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1054462), 1907 novel by [Charles Howard Hinton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Howard_Hinton), available for free from [Eldritch Press](http://eldritchpress.org/chh/h9.html), reviewed [here](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf208) by Alex Kasman.

["Message Found in a Copy of *Flatland*"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?44118), 1983 short story by [Rudy Rucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rudy_Rucker), available for free from [the author's web site](http://www.rudyrucker.com/transrealbooks/completestories/#_Toc21), reviewed [here](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf92) by Alex Kasman.

[*Flatterland: Like Flatland, Only More So*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?834725), 2001 novel by [Ian Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ian_Stewart_(mathematician)), reviewed [here](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/mfview.php?callnumber=mf198) by Alex Kasman and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatterland) by Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the answers above, there are many books and stories which deal with both higher- and lower-dimensional beings. Off the top of my head, *Fantasia Mathematica*, *Mathematical Magpie*, *The Boy Who Reversed Himself*.

The first two are collections of short stories, poems, and short texts which explore Math Fiction. Stories like Star, Bright, And He Built A Crooked House, The No-Sided Professor are certainly examples of folks fiddling with dimensions and are contained therein. Star, Bright is a story about a little girl who is a hyper-genius and is the next step in human evolution. She and a neighboring boy have fun traveling through time by manipulating the fourth dimension. Crooked House is written by Heinlein about a narcissistic architect who builds a tesseract house. No-sided Professor is the first story in a series about an outrageous mathematician who does impossible math- in this case, invents the no-dimensional figure. People believe it is a trick, and he takes one into the higher dimensions to prove himself.

The last book is a young adult book about a girl who realizes that a boy in her school occasionally seems reversed left to right. She finally convinced him to explain why and we find out that he is a member of a family who are guardians of the lower dimensions- our 3D world guards the 2D world, guardians in the 2D world protect the 1D world, and continuing up. Down here near the bottom, the job is particularly crucial, likening it to ever larger billiard balls stacked atop one another, and at the very bottom the tiniest shove could simply throw the whole thing into chaos. The children explore the fourth dimension, and end up getting captured, and desperately try to come up with a way to escape.